# Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'object' at row 1 error when trying to update using Active Record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a mysql table with a column of medium text type. For a specific record I am getting this error when I using rails Active Record and mysql2 to update the record(saving it using AR with the same values does not create an error). When I duplicate the record and set the value of the med text attribute to an empty string there is no error. The size of this record's attribute/column is 69000 characters which is right above a standard text limit but this shouldn't be an issue since this is a med text type. When I manipulate the record from the db console I don't have a problem either. What is the cause of this and how do I fix it?

Comment: How do you defined the column in the migration?

Comment: There is a change_column migration that defines it as :mediumtext, the schema file declares it as: t.text "column", size: :medium,  and in the database it is mediumtext